# copying uncopied rows of tables in all specified schemas from a pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I have a pg_dump of a database from a database server, and I've previously restored a different version a previous dump.

But, now I'd like to copy only the uncopied rows, i.e. only the newer rows of the new dump of only the `data` schemas' tables: `place`, `venue` and `location`, other all schemas and tables are not necessary for me. Is this possible to do this when we only have pg_dump of the new database at hand? I'd like to do this because, till now I've been deleting the entire database and restoring it, not to mention some painstaking manual setup for extensions due to it being a hosted database service.

Comment: 1) What format is the `pg_dump` output? 2) There is no way to do this directly from the `pg_dump`. The safest would to restore the desired tables to a new database in the cluster. How that is done will depend on the answer to 1). Then use [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) to transfer the data via query to the existing tables.

Comment: I use the tar format for pg_dump

Comment: You can restore a specific table from the tar format by doing `pg_restore -t some_table  -f some_table.sql db.tar`. This will create a plain text version of the CREATE TABLE and COPY <table_data> to the file some_table.sql. To restore directly to a database change `-f some_table.sql` to `-d the_db`. **WARNING** do not do the restore to the database that already has the table and data. More information can be found here [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html).